# Compute when input gets changed by slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue getting this to work.

I need to compute input `bmi_val` when one of the other 2 inputs is changed. These 2 inputs could be changed by user directly (writing a value into one of them) or by jQuery slider. The first situation (input changed directly) works, but the second one I'm not able to figure out.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLh6dz2s/)

```js
//compute BMI
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#height_value, input#weight_value").on('input', function() {
       $("#height_value").ready(function() {           
           var $val2 = $('input#height_value', this).val();
           var $val1 = $('input#weight_value', this).val();
           
           var $total = $val1 / ($val2/100 * $val2/100);

           $('input#bmi_val', this).val($total);
       });
   });      
});
//slider height
$(document).ready(function() {
 $( "#height_slider" ).slider({
  range: "max",
  min: 100,
  max: 225,
  value: 175,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
   $( "#height_value" ).val( ui.value );
   $(ui.value).val($('#height_value').val());
  }
 });
 $("#height_value").keyup(function() {
  $("#height_slider").slider("value" , $(this).val())
 });
});
//slider weight
$(document).ready(function() {
 $( "#weight_slider" ).slider({
  range: "max",
  min: 35,
  max: 150,
  value: 70,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
   $( "#weight_value" ).val( ui.value );
   $(ui.value).val($('#weight_value').val());
  }
 });
 $("#weight_value").keyup(function() {
  $("#weight_slider").slider("value" , $(this).val())
 });
});
```

```html
<form name="BMI" method="POST">
  <div id="height_slider"></div>
  <input type="text" name="height" id="height_value" value="175" />
  <br>

  <div id="weight_slider"></div>
  <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight_value" value="70" />
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="bmi_val" id="bmi_val" readonly>
</form>
```

Comment: a jsfiddle will be nice.

Comment: @JC Sama: JSFiddle added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually trigger `input` event, when `slide` is fired, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLh6dz2s/2/)

```
$( "#height_slider" ).slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 100,
    max: 225,
    value: 175,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#height_value" ).val( ui.value ).trigger('input');
        $(ui.value).val($('#height_value').val());
    }
});
```